# UK Visa Second Application

Tags: visas, uk

I did an application for the UK for a couple who had four kids at the time. They failed to add all four kids' information and rather added three as the fourth one was just born and feared they might be refused for leaving the small one at home during their time of travel. Can they add that information in the new second application now?

Comment: Was the first application refused?  If so, why?

Comment: The application was successful

Comment: Sooner or later your couple will have a problem. If they don't declare the fourth child they run the risk that UK immigration have found out about it and will ask why. Obviously, if they're wanting to travel with the child they'll need a visa and UK immigration can check their previous application and want to know why the child wasn't mentioned then. Similarly, there could be questions if they just declare now. I can't tell you what they should do, but it's never a good idea to lie on an immigration form.